# How should I print the results of an algorithm to file in R?

Tags: r, string

Let's say I run `randomForest` in R. After training and testing, I could type

```
rf
```

(where `rf` is my randomForest model) and R will print some information about the model.

How could I store this output to a string variable and then store in text file?

I tried

```
text = c()
text = paste (text, print (rf))
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`sink()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sink.html)

```
sink("output.txt")
rf
sink()
```